# Misunderstanding of Function Notation

Tags: differential-equations

I have:

```
sol = DSolve[{y'[t] == y[t]^2 - y[t], y[0] == c}, y[t], t];
y[t_, c_] := y[t] /. First[sol];
```

Then:

```
y[t,c]
```

Produces this output:

-(c/(-c - E^t + c E^t))

But this:

```
y[0,1]
```

Produces this output:

y[0]

I was expecting:
\begin{align*}
y(t,c)&=\frac{c}{c+(1-c)e^t}\\
y(0,1)&=\frac{1}{1+(1-1)e^0}\\
y(0,1)&=1
\end{align*}

What is wrong with my thinking?

Moreover, this worked just fine:

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[y[t, c], {c, -1, 2, 0.25}]], {t, 0, 3}, 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {x, y}, PlotRange -> {-7, 8}]
```

Producing this image:

[image]

And one more question, if I may. What is the easiest way to remove those vertical asymptotes from my image?

Comment: USe `y[t_, c_] := Evaluate[y[t] /. First[sol]]`

Comment: Or just use `Set` rather than `SetDelayed`: `y[t_, c_] = y[t] /. First[sol]`;

Comment: @BobHanlon: I can't tell you how helpful this is. What I really need to do is study the difference between Set and SetDelayed. Can you point me to the best piece of documentation I should read to really learn the difference between these two?

Comment: Read all of the documentation for `Set` at http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html and `SetDelayed` at http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html, and when defining functions use `Definition` (`?`) or `Information` {`??`) to see how `Set` or `SetDelayed` affect the `DownValues` for the symbol.

Comment: Excellent, will do!

Comment: It turns out that if you go into SetDelayed at reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html, then from the Tutorials, select ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions and you get an excellent presentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `c` does not appear in `y[t] /. First[sol]` explicitly.

I guess all you need to do is remove the colon in your assignment for `y[t,c]`. There is no need for a delayed evaluation, because `sol` gives a closed-form solution for any `c`.

As to your question about removing the "asymptotes", you could have a look at `Piecewise[]`, e.g.

```
f[x_] = 1/x;
g[x_] = Piecewise[{{0, -.1 < x < .1}, {f[x], True}}]

Plot[f[x], {x, -1, 1}]
Plot[g[x], {x, -1, 1}]
```

> [image]
>   [image]

You can move the plateau thus created out of sight by adjusting the height of the plateau and tweaking the `PlotRange` option.